# Extracting src from an image tag

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am working in JavaScript. My code is:

```
arr = [];
var divData =    document.getElementById("mainDiv").getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < divData.length; i++) {
if (divData[i].style.border == "2px solid black"){}
 else {
var imageSrc = divData[i].innerHTML;
arr.push(divData[i].innerHTML);
```

Above code is used to extract the childDiv which contains an image from mainDiv.

```
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Above code is used to printing that image tag.
The issue is I just want to print the src of the image but not the whole tag.
How to do this?? 
ANy help would be great.
My HTML is :

```
   <div id="mainDiv"class="header" style="width:113%;margin-top:-24px;height:45px;line-height:45px;margin-left:-17px;background-color:#1156AB;color:white;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;margin-bottom:10px;"><div id="pic" style:"padding:5px"></div></div>
```

Comment: Why are you parsing the `src` from a string, when you could just iterate through the images themselves, and retrieve the `src` property?

Comment: Could you show your HTML for `#mainDiv` and its contents?

Comment: `arr.push(divData[i].children[0])` then `alert(arr[i].src)` Assuming the image is the first child of the div.

Comment: Wow, you are trying to show image inside a `div`? What exactly are you trying to get as `src`?

Comment: If you really see an image where `#pic` is, the src must be on your CSS. It's not trivial to extract it from there. Why not using an `<img>` tag?

Comment: @ATOzTOA I did print the image in the div and got the image tag by coding imageSrc=divData[i].innerHTML; but now the problem is how i can get the src split from that img tag ??

Comment: @ bfavaretto Oh shit i forgot to brief but the image tag is dynamically created on the click of a button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
var imageSrc = divData[i].getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
arr.push(imageSrc);
```

Comment: `code is used to printing that image tag` how is there not an image tag in there, but you say there is in your question?

Comment: Well i want to extract it from innerHTML

Comment: There is no image and no `src` in your HTML.

Comment: Oh shit i forgot to brief but the image tag is dynamically created on the click of a button

Comment: Is it going to be created inside the `div` with id `pic`?

Comment: Then this code will work. Can you dynamically add the image and then take a snap of the HTML code?

Comment: Actually the image is taken by camera and then placed in the div with id="pic"

Comment: Thanx ATOzTOA for your response your code is working well .. +1 fof this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like that:

```
var imgs = doc.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
imgs[0].getAttribute("src"); 
//or
imgs[0].src
```

Comment: I know but how i can get to this ??

Comment: i want to extract the source after getting the innerHTML .

Comment: I want to get src from imageSrc